# Все думают, что … (общий член?)

Tags: запятые

Все думают, что мы с тобой подрались(,) и ты тяжело ранил меня.

Возможна ли в данном примере авторская пунктуация, если запятая будет означать «и поэтому»? Нужна ли там запятая в принципе? Можно ли считать общими членами «Я считаю, что…», «Казалось, что…», «Я видел, что…» и т. п.? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Не "Заранее благодарю", а лайки нужно ставить и галочки. А вы по какой-то неведомой причине принципиально этого не делаете, зато в комментариях иногда просто пишите "спасибо" (но без лайков). Это очень странно. Нет желания вам отвечать.

Comment: oleedd, извините, я думала, это не причиняет особых неудобств. Я просто привыкла быстро читать ответы и сразу сворачивать страницу, не обращая на такие мелочи внимания. Впрочем, спасибо, что сказали об этом. Надеюсь, это больше не странно для вас:)

Comment: Вот теперь уже совсем другое дело))) Просто вам и раньше об этом часто говорили другие. Может быть, вы просто не видели тех комментариев. Просто получается, что если нет лайков, то ответ **был бесполезен** и никому не помог, а тогда и смысла отвечать нет.

Comment: Дополнительная информация: Лайк и галочку возможно комбинировать (возле одного ответа). На этом сайте, можно сказать, уже сложилась такая традиция.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если там поставить запятую, то часть после запятой уже не будет относится к "все думают" — она будет самостоятельной. А смысл такой:
*Все думают, что мы с тобой подрались, и, вообще-то, ты тяжело ранил меня.

Ты тяжело ранил меня, и все думают, что мы с тобой подрались.*
То есть часть после запятой уже превращается из предположения в утверждение. Думаю, это совсем не то, что нужно.

Запятая не может означать «и поэтому».

> Нужна ли там запятая в принципе?

Не нужна.

> Можно ли считать общими членами «Я считаю, что…», «Казалось, что…», «Я видел, что…» и т. п.?

Однозначно можно. Но функцию общего элемента больше выполняет именно слово "что".